# Hash subtraction in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 hashes (that later will be converted to array, not sure if this is relevant):

```
Hash1 = {"X"=>2, "Y"=>1, "Z"=>1}

Hash2 = {"X"=>1, "Y"=>1}
```

I need to subtract them like (Hash3 = Hash1 - Hash2), and I need the result of Hash3 to be, in this case :

```
Hash3 = {"X"=>1, "Y"=>0, "Z"=>1}
```

All examples and answers I've seen led to results where the key which had value equals 0 (Y) to be absent in the resulting hash, which is not what I need.

I'm using Ruby 2.3.3 and Rails 5.0

Comment: Say more about your example: it's not clear. Why is `{"X" => 1}` selected over `{"X" => 2}`? Where does `{"Y" => 0}` come from?

Comment: Just edited with corrected syntax

Comment: the value of the hashes indicates quantity, so, I have the first Hash which is my "stock" and the second Hash which is my "currently in use" I need the resulting Hash to be the "available". The subtraction is only for the values

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can [`merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) them:

```
h1 = {"X"=>2, "Y"=>1, "Z"=>1}
h2 = {"X"=>1, "Y"=>1}

h1.merge(h2) { |k, v1, v2| v1 - v2 }
#=> {"X"=>1, "Y"=>0, "Z"=>1}
```

Whenever a key is present in both hashes, the block is called to determine the new value.

---

Due to this behavior it will **not** result in negative values if a key is only present in `h2`:

```
h1 = {"X"=>2, "Y"=>1}
h2 = {"X"=>1, "Y"=>1, "Z"=>1}

h1.merge(h2) { |k, v1, v2| v1 - v2 }
#=> {"X"=>1, "Y"=>0, "Z"=>1}
```

You might expect:

```
#=> {"X"=>1, "Y"=>0, "Z"=>-1}
```

Which is what [tadman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45088527/477037) would return.

Comment: That's a really nice feature of `merge`. Didn't know it did that.

Comment: +1, This 'subtract two hashes' case is actually the use case for the documentation: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge

Comment: @MickeySheu oh indeed :-)

Comment: Great. This is the easiest way, and luckily my model does not allow the second hash to be greater than the first one. Thanks

Comment: If `h1 = { "X"=>2, "Y"=>1, "Z"=>1 }`, `h2 = { "X"=>1, "Y"=>1, "W"=>2 }` 
and the desired return value is `{ "X"=>1, "Y"=>0, "Z"=>1 }`, one could write `h1.merge(h2.select { |k,_| h1.key?(k) }) { |k, v1, v2| v1 - v2 } #=> {"X"=>2, "Y"=>0, "Z"=>1}`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not too difficult if you break it down into two steps:

```
def hash_sub(a, b)
  (a.keys + b.keys).uniq.map do |k|
    [ k, a[k].to_i - b[k].to_i ]
  end.to_h
end

hash_sub({"X"=>2, "Y"=>1, "Z"=>1}, {"X"=>1, "Y"=>1})
# => {"X"=>1, "Y"=>0, "Z"=>1}
```

The first step is to compute all the possible (unique) keys by combining the keys from the two hashes, and then convert to a new hash by subtracting one from the other, forcing conversion to an integer with `.to_i`.

Comment: `(a.keys + b.keys).uniq` can be shorted to `(a.keys | b.keys)`

Comment: @Stefan That's true. I was tempted to go with that, but it seemed more *mysterious*.

Comment: @tadman it's quite common to think of `|` as "set union" (as in "A|B := elements present in A or B"). Knowing that, `|`'ing key sets makes perfect sense. :)

Comment: @tadman I blame Rdoc. It gather's all symbolic methods at the top but puts [`|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-7C) at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can also map them (but the merge solution is better since it will take care of getting you the values from 2 even if the key is not present in 1):

```
hash3 = hash1.map{|k,v| { k: (v-(hash2[k.to_s] || 0)) }.stringify_keys }
```

This will yield an array